# FireDAC, pass "secure-auth=OFF" to client library

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-xe6, firedac

I'm trying, unsuccessfuly, to connect to an old mysql server (pre-4.1) that does not support secure passwords, from a client machine that has MySQL 5.6 client library installed, using FireDAC in DelphiXE6. Such a connection, by default, would be refused BY THE CLIENT (not server), giving the error:

```
[FireDAC][Phys][MySQL] Connection using old (pre-4.1.1) authentication protocol refused (client option 'secure_auth' enabled)
```

Now, on command line client, getting this to work is as simple as adding the `--skip-secure-auth` parameter. The following works fine:

```
mysql -h ipaddr -u user --password=mypass -D database --skip-secure-auth
```

However, in FireDAC I was unable to find a way to pass that parameter to client library. Adding "`secure-auth=off`" to TFDConnection parameters does not work, that parameter is simply ignored.

I did try to set my.ini on client to disable secure-auth as follow, but that didnt have any effect either.

```
[client]
secure-auth=OFF

[mysql]
secure-auth=OFF
```

At this point, I seem stuck. MYSQL_SECURE_AUTH and secure_auth field of protocol options is defined in FireDAC.Phys.MySQLCli, but I seem to be unable to go from TFDConnection to whatever class that holds MySQLcli.

I hope I was able to describe my problem clearly enough. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think [`this way`](http://pastebin.com/8u0t8uXC) you can set that option (just like `TADPhysMySQLConnection.InternalConnect` method does; though I'm not sure about the value that should be set there).

Comment: tried your suggestion, however there is the problem of "when" to do it. At OnBeforeConnect, both Driver and ClipObj are nil, not created yet. At DriverCreated of TFDMySQLPhysDriverLink, I get driver created, but ClipObj (session) is still not created. Tho, your idea seems to be in the right direction. I was trying to use mysql_options_() of driver object.

Comment: Good question! `InternalConnect` does not seem to fire any event after the session object is created but before it actually connects to the server. And if you let the connection fail, is the session object released ? (sorry, don't have environment to test)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your best option is to patch your client (one-line fix) so that "secure-auth=OFF" works as it should: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75425